# How to Report a Feature Request to GNOME Dock Settings

Tags: gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock, 19.04

In Ubuntu 19.04, what is the easiest way to determine the name of the package responsible for Dock settings and what is the best way to submit a feature request for that package?

In my 3 4K monitor set up, I'd like the dock to appear on my

1. bottom monitor > Left-Side
2. top-right monitor > Left-Side
3. top-left monitor > Don't show at all

[image]

As you can see, the UI (shown above on my top-right monitor) only allows the dock to show on **all monitors or one monitor**. Additionally, if you do show the dock on multiple monitors, the dock has to be located on the **same side** of all monitors. This is terribly inflexible. Even Windows 10 allows this, so I expect better out of GNOME 3.

Basically, I'm trying to reduce mouse-travel to the dock and save some screen space. By putting a dock on my "top-right monitor left-side", Both top monitors can share that dock (which saves screen space on the top-left monitor while also making the dock accessible without too much mouse-travel on that top-left monitor).

Perhaps the developer of this UI could not imagine someone wanting what I want here. I'd like to submit a feature request that will get to the eyes of someone who might actually be willing to make this more flexible.

So:

1. How can I determine the package associated with the dock?
2. What command can I type to generate a bug-report for that package
   (so that bug report includes all the versioning that a bug-report
   reader might care about)?

Comment: something like this? https://launchpad.net/lswitcher If so we can force eh ask Jacob :+

Answer (score 1):

The dock in Ubuntu 17.10 and later is provided by the [`gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock) package.

You can report bugs here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock (click [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock/+filebug)).